# MySQL Group_By with attributes as columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following output from some joins I am doing:

```
------------------------------------------------
      id             title              date
------------------------------------------------
       1             title1            01/01/03
       1             title3            01/01/05
       2             title2            01/01/02
       2             title3            01/01/01
       2             title1            01/01/06
       3             title1            01/01/07 
       3             title2            01/01/09
```

Im wondering if its possible to set-up my query output so that I have a distinct id per row. This could be achieved by allowing the title attribute to be set as a column like so?

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
      id             title1       title2        title3     
-----------------------------------------------------------
       1             01/01/03      null        01/01/05
       2             01/01/06    01/01/02      01/01/01
       3             01/01/07    01/01/09        null
```

I'm not sure if this is just crazy talk, but thought something could be setup by using GROUP_BY? I may be well off track here though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need basic conditional aggregation, assuming that there are exactly three titles:

```
select id,
       max(case when title = 'title1' then `date` end) as title1,
       max(case when title = 'title2' then `date` end) as title2,
       max(case when title = 'title3' then `date` end) as title3
from table t
group by id;
```

This method works only when you know the list of columns that you want in the resulting SQL.  If you have a variable number of potential columns, then you have two choices.  The first is to use `group_concat()` to produce something like this:

```
id          title1:date; title2:date . . .
```

The SQL for this is:

```
select id, group_concat(title, ':', date separator '; ')
from table t
group by id;
```

The other is to create the necessary SQL in a string and use `prepare` and `exec` to run it.